# JQuery children element set event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create an event for each (a) element in a list (ul). But im doing something wrong

```
function EnableAjaxOnMenu(ElementID, TagName) {

    var elm = jQuery("#" + ElementID).children(TagName).click(function () {

        GetPageByUrl(jQuery(this).attr("href"));
        //ChangeSelectedMenuItem(this);
        return false;
    });

}
```

Does anyone know what im doing wrong here, as far as I can see it won't even create an event?

Comment: can we see some html as well please

Comment: GetPageByUrl i don't think is a jquery function lets see that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing the `<ul>` ID, then you'll need [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to find the `<a>` elements within, since they're not *direct* children, like this:

```
jQuery("#" + ElementID).find(TagName).click(...);
```

Or, like this:

```
jQuery("#" + ElementID + " " + TagName).click(...);
```

Comment: Just beat me to it! `children( )` -> selects against direct descendants. `find( )` -> selects against all descendants.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was exactly what I was looking for:) Is there anything I should do to check the question as answered?